# Not gate dividing voltage

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, resistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfsbj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am working on a binary calculator using 2n3904 NPN transistors. I noticed when using a NOT gate the voltage gets divided when running the ouput of the NOT gate to a 10K resistor that controls the base pin of another transistor. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: We love schematics. Much better than words. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. It's really easy to use. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: A full circuit would be usefull. This site has an integrated circuit editor which should be a dequate for this kind of circuit.

Comment: Can I edit my post

Comment: @user3657511 Yes, you can edit your post by clicking the "edit" text below the post. Additionally, the post editor has a built-in schematic editor which can be accessed by clicking the `{}` button at the top of the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Because R4 is connected to the base of Q2 -- when Q1 is off, it forms a load on Q1's collector (R1), so the voltage there won't rise above about 6 V.

This doesn't really affect the performance of the NOT gate -- its threshold is about 0.8 V, so any input higher than this will be a '1'.

Given that the transistors have a beta (gain) of well over 50, you don't need to use 10k -- you could use (say) 100k. This would allow the '1' voltage to rise to (approximately) 9V*100k/(100k+4.7k) = 8.6 V